# Part of my PHP code is is not working on the client's server

Tags: php

I am using this code to post an address to a form in an iframe. Everything works perfectly locally and on my own web server, but when I try it on the client's server, it just displays this code as text in the form field in the iframe  Any idea why it wouldn't work here? The client is running a slightly newer version of PHP than me as well.

```
<iframe name="iFrameName" id="iFrameName" frameborder="0" height="600px" width="700px"></iframe>

<?php 
   if ($_POST["FormtoCRM"] == "Login")
    {
?>
        <form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/iframe.cfm" method="post" target="iFrameName" id="FormtoCRMForm" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" input name="address" value="<?= $_POST['address'] ?>">


                    </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("FormtoCRMForm").submit();
</script>


<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>
```

My guess is that short open tags are not enabled in your `PHP` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration option is turned off on their hosting environment. Instead of `<?= $_POST['address'] ?>` use `<?php echo $_POST['address'] ?>`.